# Как подключиться к разделу для просмотра файлов в Linux?

Tags: linux

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как просмотреть файлы из раздела `/dev/sda3`?

Answer (score 4):

Его бы сначала mount

```
mount /dev/sda3 /home/user/windows
ls /home/user/windows
```

Comment: А что, mount уже все файловые системы сам опознаёт?

Comment: Ставлю на то что там ntfs. Проблемы возникнут только если он убитый

Comment: можно добавить -o ro, чтобы не испортить ничего

Comment: Маунт пробует все, на которые есть мортировщик

Answer (score 1):

mount.

А для того чтобы постоянно монтировать фс при запуске системы нужно добавить запись в /etc/fstab.
(подробности в fstab(5)).

Примерно так будет выглядить строка которую нужно добавить:

```
/dev/sda7       /media/windows/d(путь для монтирования)  ntfs  r,user,auto     0       2
```